# HTML 5 Video Player Customization for pausing after 10% of total video play back and it should stop

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp-2.0

As per my clients requirement the video should be played for 10% of all the video playback time and it should pause after 10%, should ask for payment. If the user is already subscribed then he should not be prompted for payment. I'm considering video.js script. Is there any other player to implement the functionality or any code to do this. Please reply soon.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find out the duration of your video,

```
myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    console.log(videoPlayer.duration);
});
```

Then calculate 10% of that duration .
then pause the video after that time period using
//assume requiredminutes variable is 10% of duration of video

```
myVideoPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= requiredminutes * 60 * 1000) {
        this.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: IS there any demo version of it. Could you share the whole code. Snippets is difficult to get. and the 10% value is a dynamic value

Comment: I dont have demo version of it.. If 10% is dynamic then create a function and pass the parameter as % value..and then get the actual time to be played..